# Moscapsule prevents app from being built for watchOS due to missing dependencies

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm new to CocoaPods and Swift and I've been getting a certain error after adding targets for a watch extension:

```
Showing Recent Issues
Target 'Moscapsule' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit 
dependency for 'Moscapsule.framework' because it doesn't contain 
platform 'watchsimulator' in its supported platforms 'iphonesimulator,
iphoneos'
```

Of course, then it goes off looking for dependencies where it won't find them.  I've tried various ways of including watchos as a platform in my Podfile, and I've tried including various files in the location that it's looking for them.  It should also be noted that I'm not even using Moscapsule in the watch extension yet, and I'm not entirely sure why it still needs it.

Most answers that I've found online to this error are from before CocoaPods supported watchOS or haven't been of much help.  I've tried about everything that I can think of.  I'm wondering if maybe Moscapsule doesn't support watchOS, and if not, is there a better MQTT module to use?

Comment: Did you by chance figure this out?  I'm looking into something similar and from what I've read it seems like mqtt is not possible on the watch

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Podspec for Moscapsule defines this pod as iOS for the platform.

https://github.com/flightonary/Moscapsule/blob/master/Moscapsule.podspec

If it was built for WatchOS as well, you would see that included in the platform line.  iOS, watchOS, and tvOS are all different platform definitions for pods and each hav different libraries and capabilities.